# only have 1 active ICalculateScore.CalculateScore?

Tags: encog

I have a class that implements ICalculateScore in C# Encog 3.2.  The "CalculateScore" method is a long running, CPU intensive task.  I would like to make sure that during an iteration, only 1 call to the CalculateScore is active at once.

setting RequireSingleThreaded to true I was hoping would do the trick but did not.

Is there a Parallel.ForEach statement or something in the Encog code that could be changed to a normal non-parallel method?

Possible to tell Encog to only have 1 active ICalculateScore.CalculateScore?
Thanks,
Dan Hickman

Comment: Would throwing an exception on reentrancy be enough?  Or are you looking for an encog-centric solution?

Comment: tell me more please.  are you saying something like declaring a static variable that tracks what is active and then throwing an error if something is already active?  does Encog automatically retry?

Comment: I have no idea what Encog is or how it works.  I can tell you how to safely prevent reentrancy within a method body.  But you either skip execution or throw an exception.  I don't know how Encog would handle this, or if it would not work in your application :/  FYI, I'm a FOP man myself.

Comment: What training method are you using?  It is up to each trainer to individually respect the RequireSingleThreaded flag.  Perhaps one of them is not.

Comment: I am using the TrainEA trainer.  My example code is very similar to the Pluralsite course sample code for solving the Traveling salesmen problem using Genetic Evolution.  Hope that helps.